# How to customize the URL in Yii?

Tags: url, controller, yii

Now i am developing one simple application using Yii. now i have one doubt in customize the URL in my application. 
My URL is like [www.mywebapp.com/site/index/id/2/uid/3/text/some_text/#2](http://www.mywebapp.com/site/index/id/2/uid/3/text/some_text/#2).
I want this url like www.mywebapp.com/site.index. but i also want $_REQUEST['id'], $_REQUEST['uid'], $_REQUEST['text'] for condition purpose.

I also refer the Yii url manager website. but i dont have any idea. i refer the data from this site [Yii Url Management](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url) www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url.

i redirect this url www.mywebapp.com/site/index/id/2/uid/3/text/some_text/#2 from controller to index so i want the index url like www.mywebapp.com/site.index.

if you know about that. help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change separator like this

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => array(
                '<controller:\w+>.<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
),
),
```